# Opacity of a viewport

Tags: three.js

I use multiple viewports like in this example http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_multiple_views.html But one of my viewports is overlapping the other. The overlapping one should be semi-transparent that the user can see the underlying viewport as well. Is this possible?

Thank you ;)

Comment: try on alpha values(0 - 1) with the background color...

Comment: Set the opacity attribute of he div element which contains the canvas

Comment: I can set the alpha value of the clear color. But this currently has no effect. I guess the clear color has nothing to do with the opacity of the viewport anyway. Using the opacity of the div element is no solution for me because I use only one canvas.